# Errror: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to write a javascript and execute it in a Html file. I can run the Javascript file on my own computer without problems, but when I add it in a Html file and run it in a browser I got an Cors Error. I added the mode: 'no-cors'. After that, I got a 'SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input'. I can still only run the Javascript part so I am completely lost in trying to find the syntaxerror. Does anyone have a clue?

```
<html>
  <body>
<script>

var apiUrl = 'https://bulkfollows.com/api/v2';

// define the data to be sent to the API
var data = {
  key: "key",
  action: "balance"
};

fetch(apiUrl, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  mode: 'no-cors',
  body: JSON.stringify(data)
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => console.log(data))
  .catch((error) => console.log("Error: " + error));

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The dev tools provide a **Network** tab. Is the resource _found_ (e.g. HTTP 200 response)? Inspect the response that you’re getting from the API. It’s very likely an empty string.

Comment: Setting `no-cors` mode is not a solution to your actual issue, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe

Comment: Yes I get a 200, and I cannot see the answer in the Network tab, because it says 'No data found for resource with given header.'

Answer (score 1):

Try this. your error will be solved. but for cors,  setting cors will not solve your problem . check comment

```
 fetch(apiUrl, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  mode: "no-cors",
  body: JSON.stringify(data)
})
  .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw response; 
        }
        return response.json();
    })
  .then((data) => console.log(data))
  .catch(function(error) {
        console.log( error)
  });
```

Comment: Thanks!!
I get this now in console:
{type: 'opaque', url: '', redirected: false, status: 0, ok: false, …}